# Evaluate the following Integration--

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the following Integration $$\int \frac{\cos^9 x}{\sin^3 x + \cos^3 x} \,dx$$

I tried, but this problem is very difficult to me. any help?

Comment: Try dividing by $\cos^{3}x$ both num and denom and then put $\tan x = t$. It should lead to a rational function.

Comment: I did try that but I couldn't cpmplete

Comment: Try using sum of cubes for the denominator: $(a^3+b^3)=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$. It would simplify the denominator to $(sin(x)+cos(x))(-sin(x)cos(x)$)

Comment: A symmetric *definite* integral, such as from $0$ to $\pi/2$, is much easier.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

As suggested by Paramanand Singh in a comment, change variable $x=\tan^{-1}(t)$. This makes $$\int \frac{\cos^9 (x)}{\sin^3 (x) + \cos^3 (x)} \,dx=\int\frac{dt}{\left(t^2+1\right)^4 \left(t^3+1\right)}$$ Now, using partial fraction decomposition the new integrand becomes $$\frac{-11 t-5}{16 \left(t^2+1\right)}+\frac{2 t-1}{3 \left(t^2-t+1\right)}-\frac{3
   (t-1)}{8 \left(t^2+1\right)^2}+\frac{t+3}{4 \left(t^2+1\right)^3}+\frac{t+1}{2
   \left(t^2+1\right)^4}+\frac{1}{48 (t+1)}$$ which is not too complex.

I am sure that you can take from here.

**Edit**

For the first term $$\frac{-11 t-5}{16 \left(t^2+1\right)}=-\frac{11}{32}\frac{2t}{t^2+1}-\frac{5}{16}\frac{1}{t^2+1}=-\frac{11}{32}\frac{(t^2+1)'}{t^2+1}-\frac{5}{16}\frac{1}{t^2+1}$$ For the second term $$\frac{2 t-1}{3 \left(t^2-t+1\right)}=\frac{1}3 \frac{2 t-1}{t^2-t+1}=\frac{1}3 \frac{(t^2-t+1)'}{t^2-t+1}$$

Comment: thank you, but I really couldn't!!!

Comment: I add to my post for the first term.

Comment: man, you know this question is hard, and I'm beginner, so if you give me your answer to study it, I'll appreciate it

Comment: Could you show us what you tried ? All of us are willing to hep you but not to do your homework. So, explain and tell where you are stuck.

Comment: this is not my homework, I'm trying to learn calculus on my own, if this Integration limited it would be easy to solve, but the problem it's not limited